# LESS compile error

Tags: css, compiler-errors, less, media-queries, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using Incident57's CodeKit pre-processor to compile a series of less files that are being imported and minified into a single CSS file called template.css.

However, after making some edit (and I have no idea what edit caused this) I have started to get non_object_property_callError

```
non_object_property_callError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of null in /Volumes/Clients/htdocs/ergonomiq/domains/clients/polaris5/less/mediaqueries.less:14:2
13  h1 {
14      font-size: 100px;
15      margin-bottom: 60px;
```

template.less imports 12 files:

```
@import "cssindex.less";
@import "fonts.less";
@import "colors.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
@import "base.less";
@import "skeleton.less";
@import "flexslider.less";
@import "prettyPhoto.less";
@import "layout.less";
@import "scrollbars.less";
@import "mediaqueries.less";
```

Additionally, fonts.less itself imports 5 files

```
@import "font-awesome.less";
@import "font-awesome-ie7.less";
@import "font.bebas.less";
@import "font.leaguegothic.less";
@import "font.sourcesanspro.less";
```

The error seems to be related to / associated with the media queries.less file

```
/* Media Queries CSS File
================================================== */

/* Smaller than 1024 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
     .title { 
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 110px;
    }
    #intro {
        height: 600px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        &.small {
            font-size: 60px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    }
}

/* Smaller than 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    nav {
        ul {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    .title {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .mobnav {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999;
        top: 0.1em;
        right: 0.1em;
        width: 100px;
        height: 49px;
    }
    .mobico {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: @black;
        color: @white;
        z-index: 9990;
        overflow: hidden;
        a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 0;
            font-family: @baseFontFamily
            font-size: 1.5em;
            color: @gray85;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            border-bottom: solid 1px @gray50;
        }
    }
    .menusel {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999;
        top: 0.7em;
        right: 0.1em;
        width: 40px;
        height: 49px;
    }
    nav.is-sticky .mobnav, .mobnav {
        display: inline;
    }
    #about {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}


/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    nav, nav.is-sticky {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 52px;
    }
    .title {
        padding-top: 55px;
    }
    .logo1, .menusel, .mobnav, nav .mobnav {
        display: inline;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: fixed;
    }
    #intro {
        margin-top: 55px !important;
    }
    .logo {
        display: none;
    }
    #about {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .logo {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    #separator1, #separator2, #separator3 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 70px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        &.small {
            font-size: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    }
    .title {
        p {
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 28px;
        }
    }
    nav {
        ul {
            li {
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
    nav, nav.is-sticky {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 52px;
    }
    .mobnav, .menusel {
        display: inline;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.7em;
        right: 0.1em;
        height: 49px;
    }
    .logo1, .menusel, .mobnav, nav .mobnav {
        display: inline;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .intro-line {
        width: 400px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 3.5em;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    #about {
        p {
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            word-spacing: 0.4em;
        }
    }
    .serv-list, .markets-list {
        margin-top: 3em;
        h4 {
            margin-bottom: 2em;
            line-height: 1.15em;
        }
    }
}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    #separator1, #separator2, #separator3 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
    #intro {
        height: 430px;
    }
    .title {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 120px;
        p {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 28px;
        }
    }
    .intro-line {
        display: none;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        &.small {
            font-size: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 3em;
        margin-top: .5em;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
    }
    nav {
        ul {
            li {
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }
        }
    }
    #about {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    #about, #contact, #markets {
        p {
            font-size: 1.25em;
            margin-top: .5em;
            margin-bottom: .5em;
            word-spacing: 0.4em;
        }
        .copyright {
            p {
                font-size: .85em;
            }
        }
    }
    nav, nav.is-sticky {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 52px;
    }
    .logo {
        display: none;
    }
    .logo1, .menusel, .mobnav, nav .mobnav {
        display: inline;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .serv-list, .markets-list {
        margin-top: 3em;
        h4 {
            font-size: 2em;
            margin-bottom: 2em;
            line-height: 1.15em;
        }
        .roundness-red, .roundness-blue {
            padding: 1em 0;
            span, i {
                font-size: 2em;
                padding: 1.2em 1.3em;
            }
        }
        .roundness-purple, .roundness-yellow, .roundness-green {
            padding: 1em 0;
            span, i {
                font-size: 2em;
                padding: 1.2em 1.2em 1.1em 1.2em;
            }
        }
        p {
            font-size: 1.25em;
            margin-top: 2em;
            margin-bottom: .5em;
        }
    }
    .contact-info {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
}
```

Beyond that, I am completely lost.

What does **the non_object_property_callError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of null** error mean, and how do I solve it?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most frustrating thing about LESS is its less than helpful debug information.

It was a simple missing semicolon on line 57

```
    a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-family: @baseFontFamily    //missing semicolon
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: @gray85;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-bottom: solid 1px @gray50;
    }
}
```

The corrected code worked fine

```
    a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-family: @baseFontFamily;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: @gray85;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-bottom: solid 1px @gray50;
    }
}
```