# cssmin not correctly handling @import

Tags: css, gruntjs, minify, bundling-and-minification, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am using cssmin on files containing @imports.  cssmin is recursively importing local files correctly, but for imports that point to a URL the imports are left inline.  This makes the resulting minified CSS invalid because @ rules must be at the beginning of the file.  Does anyone know a good solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: Try running cssjoin then cssmin?

https://github.com/suisho/cssjoin

Or why not localize the file from import@url?

Comment: cssjoin also includes the @imports into the middle of the file. I cannot localize the url.

Comment: I had this same problem with cssmin. I was able to work around it by adding the @import statements to the start of the first file I was combining.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 8):

I have exactly the same problem with **cssmin** and **@import**, and i found a solution with **grunt concat**:

1. Create a concat grunt task that:
2. Put @import url in the begining of mified css file and replaces references of @imports url for "".
3. Execute task concat:cssImport after cssmin task.

> Grunt task Code: to execute (concat:cssImport)

```
 grunt.initConfig({     
   concat: {
      cssImport: {
            options: {

               process: function(src, filepath) {
                return "@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,900);"+src.replace('@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,900);', '');
              }
           }
         },
            files: {
                'your_location_file_origin/file.full.min.css': ['your_location_file_destination/file.full.min.css']
            }
        } )}
```

My inspiration comes from https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#custom-process-function.

Answer (score 5):

I added the `processImport: false` option to grunt.

```
'cssmin': {
  'options': {
    'processImport': false
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong! It makes grunt ignore import statements, not moving it to the top

Answer (score 2):

Use the following process:

- Install `node-less`
- import the files by compiling with `less` first
- minify with `cssmin`

**References**

- [node-less](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-less)
- [LESS compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520803/less-compile-error)

Answer (score 1):

I had something like this in the *styles.scss*:

```
@import url(custom-fonts.css);
```

My problem was the **@import wasn't able to find the files** because the root **path was missing**. Here's what I did with yeoman angular generator Gruntfile.js config:

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    root: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/'
  }
},
```

Useful link [grunt-contrib-cssmin issue #75](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/issues/75#issuecomment-36807063)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question for a very long time but i post this for anybody that looking for this issue on stack overflow ... just put your code in /*!....*/ like this:

```
/*! * @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Roboto:300,400,400i,500,700,700i'); */
```

it will be include in your destination min css but don't forget to use remote import in top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the imports at the top of my scss didn't work for me,I ended up importing the external stylesheets directly from the html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
        rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300"
              rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
......
<!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/app.css -->
  <link el="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
```