# How to make sure remote @imports are processed correctly with Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I use Grunt to build my project and [cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) task inside. My CSS file contains a remote @import statements and `grunt build` return a warning:

```
Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
>> Ignoring remote @import of "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic" as no callback given.,Ignoring remote @import of "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:500" as no callback given.
>> 2 files created. 322.48 kB → 249.05 kB
```

I've found the following information in the [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) library documentation:

> In order to inline remote @import statements you need to provide a
>   callback to minify method, e.g.:
>
> ```
> var CleanCSS = require('clean-css');
> var source = '@import url(http://path/to/remote/styles);';
> new CleanCSS().minify(source, function (errors, minified) {
>   // minified.styles
> });
> ```
>
> This is due to a fact, that, while local files can be read
>   synchronously, remote resources can only be processed asynchronously.
>   If you don't provide a callback, then remote @imports will be left
>   intact.

How can I describe a cssmin task in my Gruntfile.js to correct handling remote @import statements?

Answer (score 8):

Moving the `@import` statements to the top of the CSS file fixes it for me, I had the same problem. It seems like `cssmin` doesn't like it when `@import` statements are in the middle of the file. You can do this automatically with an `options` object in Grunt, see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454233/2142259

Comment: This in fact solves the issue because cssmin doesn´t relocate `@import`s but this also doesn´t import remote css  to avoid use of `@import`. The callback function mentioned by `clean-css` library would inline the css files remotely referenced by `@import`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not the best solution, but it worked for me when I moved all the @import statements to another file and inserted it in my html file just before my main css file.

Comment: This is effectively the same as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31174350/1677912), except for the introduction of a separate file.

Comment: So far the unique answer I saw that might inline remote css is this [answer][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173522/cssmin-not-correctly-handling-import/23944208#23944208]. But I did not test it yet.